# Push segue calling two times

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am using storyboard. for validation on push segue i am using "-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender" this method but it's calling two times means after 2 clicks it's opening next view and this method also call 2 times and i am not able to finding out the issue. Anybody can help me to solve this issue.

Here is my code -

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"pushTab"])
 {
   if ([emailTxt.text isEqualToString:@""] || [passwordTxt.text isEqualToString:@""])             
   {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please               
        put your id or password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        emailText = emailTxt.text;
        passwordText = passwordTxt.text;
        Login *loginModel = [[Login alloc]init];
        [ASKevrOperationManager login:loginModel handler:^(id object , NSError *error 
        , BOOL success)
         {
             if (success) 
             {
                 flag = true;
                 NSLog(@"Successful data = %@",object);
             }
             else
             {
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                 message:@"Wrong Id or Password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];
                 flag = false;
                 NSLog(@"Invalid Data");
             }
         }];
        if (flag == true) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
return NO; }
```

Comment: @Sunny: No.it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

try to use this method,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 //Stuff
}
```

Comment: I already used this and it was not working properly thats why i used this method

Comment: what happened previosly